# PyParsing problem: how to tell PyParsing to wait for more string in a command line interface?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to create a simple interpreter by using PyParsing module.
I searched for some documentation, but I'm unable to find something that solves my problem.
I post a simple sample of my grammar:

```
from PyParsing import *
id = Word(alphas,alphanums)
typeid = Keyword("integer") | Keyword("string")
vardef = id + ":" + typeid
vardecl = Forward()
vardecl << Literal("var") + DelimitedList(vardef)
```

So, if I parse a string containing var declarations all works, even if I define more vardef.
But, if I parse a string containing only "var i:integer," vardecl.parseString returns a parser exception.
I wnat to tell vardecl.parseString that check if the string is complete or not. If not, it ask to input other code...
It is possible? 
I googled something, but I don't find anything.

Comment: I don't think that's a PyParsing problem. Just catch the exception and get more text and reparse it.

Comment: The problem is that ParseException occurs even if I have an error on my string, for example, if I have a character not recognized by grammar.

Comment: The ParseException will include attributes (loc, col, line, lineno) to help you determine where the exception occurred - if it occurs at the end of the string, then you probably have a "need more data" problem.